# boost linker error wrong toolset

Tags: c++, boost, linker

there are many questions related to this but none so far is a solution in my case. 
I built boost 1.63 libraries with VS 2017, using toolset 14.1

The command line for building boost libs is:

```
bjam --toolset=msvc-14.1 --build-dir="libs"  --stagedir="x64" --build-type=complete stage  address-model=64 threading=multi link=static runtime-link=static
```

The 2nd lib in the build folder is

```
libboost_atomic-vc141-mt-sgd-1_63.lib
```

My project using boost is pointing to this folder. But linking with VS 2017
and Toolset 14.1 selected throws an error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_atomic-vc140-mt-sgd-1_63.lib'
```

As you can see, only the toolset in incorrect. 
Is there an additional switch and where to find ? Thank you.

One comment: i built the bjam.exe with project-config.jam setting

```
using msvc : 14.1;
```

and libraries been built lightning fast: Below 20 seconds for all x64 libraries!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost 1.63 hasn't been made compatible with Visual Studio 2017, so there's a few things you gotta do manually to fix things. In order to make sure it picks up the correct library files, you need to make edits to `auto_link.hpp`, which is found in `boost/config`. Change these lines:

```
# elif defined (BOOST_MSVC)

     // vc14:
#  define BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET "vc140"
```

To this:

```
# elif defined (BOOST_MSVC) && (BOOST_MSVC < 1910)

     // vc14:
#  define BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET "vc140"

# elif defined (BOOST_MSVC)

     // vc15:
#  define BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET "vc141"
```

And then do a clean recompile of the boost libraries, and replace the original version of this file in your includes with this modified version.